# Are they under same parent companies?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

I am looking for another answer to a problem posted earlier at MSE [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/example-where-union-of-increasing-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma-algebra), and by chance stumbled into another website called *How360* having exactly the same question and answers [*here*](http://how360.org/mathematics/833298/filtrations-and-sigma-algebras). Are they under the same parent company?

Thanks.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/scraper-sites/info) and other questions tagged ([meta-tag:scraper-sites]).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is an unrelated site that scrapes Stack Exchange posts and puts ads around them. Which by itself is allowed, as long as they give attribution to authors of posts and link back to Stack Exchange. Which they   do, at the bottom of page.

There are many such sites: some of them abide by attribution requirements, many do not. For details, see 
[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: I don't see any links to Stack Exchange or any mention of it. That could be because I don't get shown any answers due to the ad-blocker, however.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, scrapers are allowed, but SCRAPERs are not? In that case, that backronym is not ideally chosen imho.

Comment: @DanielFischer [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p7gJs.png) is what I see near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Probably the ad-blocker then, [blank for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X3UXA.png).

Comment: Nothing for me either.. I just see the question - it should either also block that too or show everything. Now it shows an unsourced quote.